# Trying to animate SVG stroke when it appears, but without luck

Tags: jquery, function, svg, path, jquery-animate

I have an SVG path and I'm trying to animate it as soon as it appears using the jquery.appear plugin.

This is what it looks like:

```
<svg class="animated" width="1170" height="350">
<path d="M60 112,L151 237,L266 113"
   style="stroke: #2c3e50;
   fill:none;
   stroke-width:3px;
   stroke-linejoin: miter;
   stroke-miterlimit: 20.0;" />
</svg>
```

and the JS:

```
function simulatePathDrawing(path) {

  var length = path.getTotalLength();

  path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'none';
  path.style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + length;
  path.style.strokeDashoffset = length;

  path.getBoundingClientRect();

  path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'stroke-dashoffset 2.5s ease-in-out';
  path.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
  path.style.strokeWidth = '3px';
  };

  $('.animated path').appear(function() {
    simulatePathDrawing(this);
  });
```

However, if I try to run it with the mouseover function it works. Any suggestions?

```
var chars = $('.animated path').on('mouseover', function(e) {
   simulatePathDrawing(this)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An SVG `path` doesn't have a width or height in the "DOM" sense.  Therefore, it cannot scroll into view for use with the appear plugin.

Instead, you could apply `appear()` on the SVG element.  Note that you initialize the plugin with the `appear()` function, and you bind it to the element using `on('appear')`:

```
$('.animated').appear();
$('.animated').on('appear', function() {
  simulatePathDrawing($('.animated path')[0]);
});
```

**Snippet** – Scroll down to see the `appear` animation:

```js
function simulatePathDrawing(path) {
  var length = path.getTotalLength();

  path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'none';
  path.style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + length;
  path.style.strokeDashoffset = length;

  path.getBoundingClientRect();

  path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'stroke-dashoffset 2.5s ease-in-out';
  path.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
  path.style.strokeWidth = '3px';
};
console.clear();

var chars = $('.animated path').on('mouseover', function(e) {
  simulatePathDrawing(this)
});

$('.animated').appear();
$('.animated').on('appear', function() {
  simulatePathDrawing($('.animated path')[0]);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top:500px;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/morr/jquery.appear/master/jquery.appear.js"></script>
<svg class="animated" width="1170" height="350">
  <path d="M60 112,L151 237,L266 113"
   style="stroke: #2c3e50;
   fill:none;
   stroke-width:3px;
   stroke-linejoin: miter;
   stroke-miterlimit: 20.0;" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your time! I want to lose the on mouseover effect, and instead make the animation run as soon as the SVG appears, but when I delete the on mouseover bit it doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: NVM, it appears that $('.animated').appear(function() did the trick :) Thank you very much for your help!